# what is the SNDR of non linear response

Tags: snr

i have an input of

$$v_{in} = \sin{(2\pi\cdot f\cdot t)}$$

$$V_{out}=0.5+10\cdot V_{in} +0.1 \cdot V_{in}^3$$

SNDR is the ration between the power of the signal and the power of the noise .
in the Vout we will have harmonics of f,3f,DC which of them i consider noise?

Comment: None of them are noise. The ones that aren't there on the input (or at a different relative amplitude or phase on the input) are distortion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *SNDR is the ration between the power of the signal and the power of
> the noise*

No, it's the ratio of the signal to the noise-plus-distortion. A very similar term is SINAD i.e. total signal in noise and distortion and, it amounts to largely the same thing.

> *in the Vout we will have harmonics of f,3f,DC which of them i consider
> noise?*

Well, none of them really. Noise is only really relevant if it's problematic and DC cannot really be regarded as problematic unless your signal is a DC signal. So your output, in the absence of any other information is: -

- DC (unwanted)
- f (the wanted signal)
- 3f (unwanted distortion)
- noise (zero)

Comment: so SNDR is the power from the cofficient of "f" divided by the power from the coefficients of 3f and power on noise?

Comment: Yes, that sounds about right.